# ExpandableListView Group View Expand Default

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have develop ExpandableListView perfectly.

In My ExpandableListView five groups are there. load first time then collapse all five group. it is default.

now my question is load first time expandablelistview at that time 2 groups are expand and other 3 groups are collapse.

so please guide me how to do?

Comment: You want to open 2 of the 5 groups when the list is loaded?

Comment: yes. now i got solution.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Now I got solution and it will work perfectly.. Please use this..

```
ExpandableListView Exlist;

Exlist.expandGroup(0);
Exlist.expandGroup(1);
```

Comment: This works great! I wanted my first section to be expanded by default when the app started, so I simply added MyListName.expandGroup(0); into onCreate and it worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: how to make all list in expandableListview to expand?

Comment: Make sure you set this after `setAdapter`. and you need to set this with index equal time with headers.

Comment: It doesnt matter where you put this code, before or after `setAdapter`. But you should put that after your set your data for adapter. This makes sens if you sets adapter and then loads your data  over a network

Answer (score 78):

I built this snippet based off Nikhil's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6185585/818674). Thought others might find it useful as well. Only works if you are using BaseExpandableListAdapter. elv

```
ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elv_main);
elv.setAdapter(adapter);
for(int i=0; i < adapter.getGroupCount(); i++)
    elv.expandGroup(i);
```

Comment: How can I expand 3 level expandableListView ?

Comment: thanq yar...helped me

Comment: This answer is best as the group count might be dynamic

Comment: @CrazyLearner: No, the Op specifically asked for another scenario: 2 groups should be opened, not all

Comment: i try this solution.but in my expandable listview only first and inbetween two groups only expanded not all.how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 6):

This is a perfect solution, it will increase automatically

```
ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elv_main);
elv.setAdapter(adapter);
for(int i=0; i < adapter.getGroupCount(); i++)
    elv.expandGroup(i);
```

but this is based on the item positions

```
ExpandableListView Exlist;
Exlist.expandGroup(0);// first item of listview
Exlist.expandGroup(1);//second item of listview
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfect solution for expanding expandable listview

```
ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
ExpandableListView expandableListView;

expandableListView.expandGroup(0);
expandableListView.expandGroup(1);

expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```